# Prevent JS code to be called more than once? ( "once and for all' behavior-attached functions )

Tags: javascript

this jquery code works fine (demo codepen ):
https://codepen.io/matoeil/pen/XxapEL

**jquery**

```
var $exposed_form=$('.views-exposed-form').clone();
$exposed_form.prependTo('.pagerer-right-pane');
```

**html**

```
<form class="views-exposed-form grid-x grid-margin-x" data-drupal-selector="views-exposed-form-users-index-page-1" action="/en/directory" method="get" id="views-exposed-form-users-index-page-1" accept-charset="UTF-8">


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'views_exposed_form' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-exposed-form.html.twig' -->


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form_element' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/form-element.html.twig' -->
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-textfield form-item-search-api-fulltext js-form-item-search-api-fulltext cell small-12 medium-6">


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form_element_label' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/form-element-label.html.twig' -->
<label for="edit-search-api-fulltext">recherche par nom</label>
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/form-element-label.html.twig' -->




<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'input__textfield' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * input--textfield.html.twig
   x input.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/input.html.twig' -->
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-search-api-fulltext" type="text" id="edit-search-api-fulltext" name="search_api_fulltext" value="" size="30" maxlength="128" class="form-text">

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/input.html.twig' -->


        </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/form-element.html.twig' -->



<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form_element' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/form-element.html.twig' -->
<div class="js-form-item form-item js-form-type-select form-item-items-per-page js-form-item-items-per-page cell small-12 medium-6">


<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'form_element_label' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/form-element-label.html.twig' -->
<label for="edit-items-per-page">VOIR</label>
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/form-element-label.html.twig' -->




<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'select' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/select.html.twig' -->
<select data-drupal-selector="edit-items-per-page" id="edit-items-per-page" name="items_per_page" class="form-select"><option value="10" selected="selected">10</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="100">100</option></select>
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/select.html.twig' -->


        </div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/form-element.html.twig' -->



<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'container' -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/container.html.twig' -->
<div data-drupal-selector="edit-actions" class="form-actions js-form-wrapper form-wrapper cell small-12 medium-6" id="edit-actions">

<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- THEME HOOK: 'input__submit' -->
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * input--submit.html.twig
   x input.html.twig
-->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/input.html.twig' -->
<input data-drupal-selector="edit-submit-users-index" type="submit" id="edit-submit-users-index" value="Apply" class="button js-form-submit form-submit">

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/input.html.twig' -->

</div>

<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/form/container.html.twig' -->



<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/views/views-exposed-form.html.twig' -->


</form>

<div class="pagerer-right-pane"></div>
```

but crashes my browser by being called many times in the drupal context.

**my library js file**

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) { // closure
    'use strict';

    Drupal.behaviors.directory = {
        attach: function (context) {
            $('main', context).ready(init);
            function init() {
    var $exposed_form=$('.views-exposed-form').clone();
$exposed_form.prependTo('.pagerer-right-pane');



            }
        }
    };
}(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings));
```

How to prevent globally this recurrent problem?

Answer (score 5):

Don't use `.ready` use `.once`. Drupal behaviors will fire on their own, so all you need is `.once`.

See: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

> When using jQuery it is standard for a large majority of situations to
>   wrap almost all code inside the $(document).ready() function, like
>   this:
>
> `$(document).ready(function () {   // Do some fancy stuff. });`
>
> This ensures that our code will only run after the DOM has loaded and
>   all elements are available. However with Drupal there is an alternate
>   better method; using the functionality of Drupal.behaviors and once().
>   If used properly this will ensure that your code runs both on normal
>   page loads and when data is loaded by AJAX (or BigPipe!) - but not
>   jQuery methods like load() which should be avoided as Drupal behaviors
>   will fail to load for loading functions other than ajax().

So you'd be looking at something like..

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  Drupal.behaviors.myBehavior = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $('.views-exposed-form', context).once('myBehaviorUniqueKeyHere').clone().prependTo('.pagerer-right-pane');
    }
  };
}(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings));
```

I would tighten up on the selectors - there could be multiples of these on one page, so make sure you're targeting the exact thing to clone and manipulate. Example, `#views-exposed-form-users-index-page-1` or using form alter to append your own unique data-attribute on the form to select by.

All thats left is using `#attached` property or other methods of attaching the JS script to the page or element.

Comment: thanks. is there a way to put it as a setting rather than having to put it for every selectors?

Comment: Like in `drupalSettings`? Yeah, but you feed into that from the PHP side.

Comment: like in drupalSettings yes :), how?